# If i am hold the mouse left click button for 10sec, mousemove too fast and suddenly release the left click,the mouseup event not triggered in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent

My  Requirement is: Move an div inside another parent div using mousemove,mouseup,mousedown event in Jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var drag = null; var Top = null; var Left = null;
            
            var O = $("#Outside").offset();
            var outsideTop = O.top;
            var outsideRight = O.left + $("#Outside").width();
            var outsideBottom = O.top + $("#Outside").height();
            var outsideLeft = O.left; var move;
            $('#Box').mousedown(function (e) {
                $("#Box").css({ "background-color": "violet" });
                drag = $(e.target);
                drag.css({ "cursor": "move" });
                var box = $("#Box").offset();
                Top = e.pageY - box.top;
                Left = e.pageX - box.left;
               
            });
            $('body').on('mouseup', function (e) {
                $("#Box").css({ "background-color": "skyblue", "cursor": "default" });
                $('body').unbind('mousemove');
                drag = null;
            });
            $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
                if (drag) {
                    drag.css({ "background-color": "greenyellow" });
                    var cursorTop = e.pageY - Top;
                    var cursorLeft = e.pageX - Left;
                    var cursorRight = (e.pageX - Left) + $("#Box").width();
                    var cursorBottom = (e.pageY - Top) + $("#Box").height();
                    if (((cursorTop >= outsideTop) && (cursorTop <= outsideBottom)) && ((cursorLeft >= outsideLeft) && (cursorLeft <= outsideRight)))
                        if ((((cursorRight) >= outsideLeft) && ((cursorRight) <= outsideRight)) && ((cursorBottom >= outsideTop) && ((cursorBottom) <= outsideBottom))) {
                            drag.offset({
                                top: e.pageY - Top,
                                left: e.pageX - Left
                            });
                        }
                }
            }).on('mouseup', function () {
                $('body').unbind('mousemove');
               drag=null;
            });
           
        });
```

```css
#Outside
{
  height:500px;
  width:1000px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:navajowhite;
  border:5px solid blue;
  margin-left:120px;
  margin-top:18px;


}
#Box
{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  /*position:absolute;*/
  background-color:lightskyblue;
  border:4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="Outside">
  <div id="Box"></div>
</div>
```

I am using , chrome browser to see the result.My  coding part is 90% is finished. but small issue is raising here.
i got an issue, if the mousemove event is too fast,the mouseup event not triggered.i need an solution

Comment: Are you sure it's because the mousemove is too fast ? When i try it don't work only if the mouse go away of the rectangle on mousedown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use   `$(document).on('mouseup'..` and `$('body').on('mouseup'...`.  The two together are conflict. I have replace body mouseup by document and remove document mouseup down your code.

Please try below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var drag = null; var Top = null; var Left = null;
            
            var O = $("#Outside").offset();
            var outsideTop = O.top;
            var outsideRight = O.left + $("#Outside").width();
            var outsideBottom = O.top + $("#Outside").height();
            var outsideLeft = O.left; var move;
            $('#Box').mousedown(function (e) {
                $("#Box").css({ "background-color": "violet" });
                drag = $(e.target);
                drag.css({ "cursor": "move" });
                var box = $("#Box").offset();
                Top = e.pageY - box.top;
                Left = e.pageX - box.left;
               
            });
            $(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
                $("#Box").css({ "background-color": "skyblue", "cursor": "default" });
                $('body').off('mousemove');
                drag = null;
                console.log("ok");
            });
            $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
                if (drag) {
                    drag.css({ "background-color": "greenyellow" });
                    var cursorTop = e.pageY - Top;
                    var cursorLeft = e.pageX - Left;
                    var cursorRight = (e.pageX - Left) + $("#Box").width();
                    var cursorBottom = (e.pageY - Top) + $("#Box").height();
                    if (((cursorTop >= outsideTop) && (cursorTop <= outsideBottom)) && ((cursorLeft >= outsideLeft) && (cursorLeft <= outsideRight)))
                        if ((((cursorRight) >= outsideLeft) && ((cursorRight) <= outsideRight)) && ((cursorBottom >= outsideTop) && ((cursorBottom) <= outsideBottom))) {
                            drag.offset({
                                top: e.pageY - Top,
                                left: e.pageX - Left
                            });
                        }
                }
            })
           
        });
```

```css
#Outside
{
  height:500px;
  width:1000px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:navajowhite;
  border:5px solid blue;
  margin-left:120px;
  margin-top:18px;


}
#Box
{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  /*position:absolute;*/
  background-color:lightskyblue;
  border:4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Outside">
  <div id="Box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your try. but if i am holding the mousemove event for 2 or 3 seconds, then ,if i am release the left click in mouse, the mouseup event not triggered.same problem raises ?

Comment: I have try with firefox, chrome and i dont reproduce your isssue. With my code working fine.

Comment: your code is correct.I am checking your code.but drag the box all sides of the page fastly,after release the left click, mouseup event not triggered  correctly.

Comment: i try it. But nothing is wrong. Console.log is correctly fired, box css color is changed corectly, and your body mousemove off is correctly apply. Please add a picture with the false result, because i dont reproduce your issue.